# Plotting a horizontal ray at the daily open on tradingview

Tags: pine-script

Trying to plot a horizontal ray at the daily open, my code doesn't plot anything for some reason

```
//@version=4
study("Opens +", overlay=true)
higherTF1 = input("D", type=input.resolution)

dailyopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF1, open)

var line1 = line.new(bar_index, dailyopen,bar_index, dailyopen,   xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid,extend=extend.right)
line.set_color(line1, color.black)
line.set_width(line1, 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// mrtuanvn
//@version=4
study("Open Ray to right", overlay=true)
higherTF1 = input("D", type=input.resolution)

dailyopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF1, open)

line1 = line.new(x1=bar_index-1, y1=dailyopen, x2=bar_index, y2=dailyopen, xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=line.style_solid,extend=extend.right, color=color.green)

line.delete(line1[1])  // remove the previous line when new bar appears
```

Comment: A temporary solution